# The process could not execute 'sp_MSadd_replcmds' on 'MY-DB'?

Tags: sql-server, transactional-replication

I am dealing with an issue reagrding transactional replication, I am taking a backup from the publisher and restoring it onto the subscriber, when I try to enable the transactional replication between the two O got the error stating The process could not execute 'sp_MSadd_replcmds' on 'MY_DB' can anyone tell me whats wrong here?

> The process could not execute 'sp_MSadd_replcmds' on 'HK-DB-PROD'.
>   (Source: MSSQLServer, Error number: 1007) Get help: help/1007 · The
>   transactions required for synchronizing the nosync subscription
>   created from the specified backup are unavailable at the Distributor.
>   Retry the operation again with a more up-to-date log, differential, or
>   full database backup. (Source: MSSQLServer, Error number: 1007) Get
>   help: help/1007 · Batches were not committed to the Distributor.
>   (Source: MSSQL_REPL, Error number: MSSQL_REPL22020) G
>   help/MSSQL_REPL22020

Comment: What version of SQL Server is on both servers?

Comment: SQL Server version 2014

Comment: Can you post the full error?

Comment: The process could not execute 'sp_MSadd_replcmds' on 'HK-DB-PROD'. (Source: MSSQLServer, Error number: 1007)

Get help: http://help/1007




· The transactions required for synchronizing the nosync subscription created from the specified backup are unavailable at the Distributor. Retry the operation again with a more up-to-date log, differential, or full database backup. (Source: MSSQLServer, Error number: 1007)

Get help: http://help/1007




· Batches were not committed to the Distributor. (Source: MSSQL_REPL, Error number: MSSQL_REPL22020)

G http://help/MSSQL_REPL22020